# 'npm install bones' installs old version of the underscore

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js

Can you please help me out with somewhat mysterious behavior of the npm install functionality.
'Npm install bones' installs old version of the underscore (1.1.7) instead of 1.4.2. The problem is that the old version contains several bugs which are causing problems in my code.

'npm install underscore' in the bones directory does the same, while it installs the correct version outside of this directory. 
According to the official specification for bones install (https://npmjs.org/package/bones), the new version should be installed.

Any ideas how to overcome this? I can just do a git clone, but I am trying to avoid this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

bones package.json has         `"underscore": "~1.3.3",` in the repo (not sure what published version has)

it will only go to the highest 1.3 version, not 1.4
but since you're only seeing 1.1 then maybe you need to run `npm update`.

https://github.com/developmentseed/bones/blob/master/package.json